# Covering a simplex efficiently by efficiently describable polytopes?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, packing-and-covering, polytopes

Take a standard simplex or cube in $\mathbb R^n$.

1. Is there a way to cover it with $O(poly(\log n))$ convex polytopes each describable by only $O(poly(\log n))$ half-plane inequalities?
2. If not what is the minimum number of convex polytopes each describable by only $O(poly(\log n))$ half-plane inequalities do we need?

By cover I mean every point in simplex is under a covering convex polytope and no point in the covering polytope is outside the cube or simplex.

Is there any good references?